# draw UML class diagram with Service classes

Tags: oop, uml, behavior, ooad

this is a small scenario of a big system.
i want to model this scenario in class diagram and then implement it in code

this is a scenario in book store.there is customer and books
customer can buy books,search books by name,and read books

class diagram implemented in following ways

1.put all operations to the customer class because customer is the one who perform these actions
but `buyBooks(),searchBook(),readBooks()` methods are not responsible for changing the state of customer class
(these methods are not working on data inside of customer class ) there for it violate basic oop principle encapsulation.

customer can buy,search,read 1 or more books therefore association marked as shown in image.

i have found lots of class diagrams draw this way when referring the INTERNET

[image]

2.
put all operations to the customer class same as above.
and mark each associations seperately, with three separate lines

associations

- customer can buy one or more books
- customer can search one or more books
- customer can read one or more books

[image]

3.in here put all operations to the service class because those methods are not responsible for changing state of neither customer,book class

and then mark association.

[image]
 - among theses which one is correct class diagram ?
 - is it  acceptable to draw service classes in uml class diagrams ?

Comment: You describe your implementation, but not your requirements. But the latter is what drives the design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either the first or the last diagram can work in my opinion (once corrected), but I lean towards the first implementation. The second one is just plain wrong.

I would use the first because a "Customer" implies a person whose exclusive purpose in the system is to interact with your Book class, especially in light of the fact that your multiplicity values indicate that a customer must associate with at least one book class. If a customer did more things than interact with books, it might be useful to abstract the things that a customer does with respect to books into a service, but I don't see the need here.

Now, your class diagram syntax is off. The arrows should be open (like `>`) rather than solid. Also, your multiplicity value on the Book class seems wrong: a book instance will presumably have zero customers associated with it if it hasn't been bought yet, and one customer associated with it if it has. If so, your multiplicity value on the book end should be `0..1`.

Finally, your second diagram is wrong because associations are by class rather than by operation; you don't put an association for each operation, but one per class.

Comment: I'm not even convinced that it needs any associations at all. From the requirements I cannot determine if there is a need to create a permanent relation between the customer and the book. If all the customer needs is to be able to read/buy/search, then the book(s) could be passed as parameters. That could be depicted as a dependency.

Comment: Open arrow? Generalization? No. Also I wonder how you can give a design suggestion without knowing the requirements.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Open arrow as in two lines, such as would be similar to this: `>`, meaning a unidirectional association. Generalization is of course a white triangle. As for what you wonder about, the first diagram models the specifications given in the OP's second paragraph, doesn't it?

Comment: Ahem, yes :-[ THIS arrow (a picture would have said more; please put the above in the answer). But the requirements are not given. There are 3 bullets under2, but that's not where I expect the requirements. They need to be at the beginning.

Comment: I agree with @geertbellekens, the description provided so far by OP do not indicate any book association, it only *might* be a dependency. Also as Thomas Kilian wrote, to answer this question we should better understand the requirements. All three diagrams might be correct depending on the requirements. It might also be that neither is correct. Anyway I would bet a nickel neither accurately represents OPs needs, at least not without significant corrections (and using *proper* is only first of many).

Comment: If a customer did more things than interact with books,
is it OK to put all that methods in customer class ??

or it is correct put services into separate classes ??

Comment: If a customer did more things than interact with books,

what is most suitable diagrams
put all that methods in customer class or 
put operations into services into separate classes ??

Comment: @ThomasKilian "Second paragraph" as in the second paragraph of the post strikes me a pretty close to the beginning. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ister I don't disagree that the requirements probably need further refinement. However, I don't think I agree that one can't start modeling without a complete understanding of requirements, either. Modeling is often a process that leads to further understanding of requirements, after all.

Comment: I meant _there is customer and books customer can buy books,search books by name,and read books._ Taken that as "requirements" leaves pretty much room for interpretation. Solution 3 (with an association iso. the dependency) seems to be best then. Speculatively.

Comment: @BobRodes yes, you can start modelling. But you can't answer the question which model is the correct one. That's what you find out through clarifying requirements. Based on the requirements listed so far I only see a dependency and no association at all.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Sure, it's a bit speculative. My attitude is that you can use simple class diagrams to model a set of requirements as they stand, and that the diagrams themselves provide insights into what is and isn't yet clear about the requirements. Iterative and incremental process and all that.

Comment: @Ister My POV is that you can use the models themselves as a tool to clarify requirements. I don't see that one can't start modeling at all until one has a complete understanding of the requirements. As the requirements become more refined, so do the models.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I use UML for: discuss with others to find the right model (or the right reality ;-). Unfortunately this can't be transported well in a SO answer as it needs a lot of practice. And even worse: the OP doesn't seem to care :-/

Comment: @ThomasKilian Eternal optimist that I am, I will say that perhaps the OP simply lacks the experience to realize that the requirements are incomplete, will have to find out the hard way down the line, and will care enough to set things right. He doesn't appear to have revisited this thread, though, so perhaps you are right.

Comment: Yes, who knows. We can just give advices here. Finally, this discussion made me upvote your answer. Hope to read more from you in the future here.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Thanks Thomas.